# comparing 2 word images using OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, sift, surf

I am working on comparing 2 word images like these:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to use OpenCV's inbuilt feature detectors for this purpose.Using SIFT and BruteForceMatcher isn't proving to be too effective as it shows a lot of matches for non-matching words also.What would be a good feature descriptor to use in this case.

Also can someone suggest a good way to quantify the probability that these 2 images are matching.

Edit:OCR can't be used as texts can be handwritten

Comment: sorry.forgot to mention..OCR can't be used as texts can be handwritten

Comment: Are they always in a very well defined location like in the examples you provided?  If so you could try template matching...

Answer (score 0):

I think that [image (contour) moments](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) should help you with matching selected symbol to latter from your alphabet. So after this you can match two words as sequences of letters.